# Using perspective transformation to change point of view of an image. Not getting desired result

Tags: python, deep-learning, opencv, vision

I am trying to change the perspective of the first image according to the second image. For finding the homography matrix I have found the four coordinates of a common object(white notice board) in both images.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijkiK.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ooFF.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
img1 = cv2.imread("rgb per.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("IR per.jpg")
img_1_coor = np.float32([[1178,425], [1201,425], [1178,439], [1201,439], [1551,778]]) #coordinate of white notice board in rgb image
img_2_coor = np.float32([[370,98], [381,103], [367,107], [380,112], [498,332]]) #coordinate of same object in IR image
for x in range(0,4):
    cv2.circle(img1,(img_1_coor[x][0],img_1_coor[x][1]),5,(255,0,0),1)
    matplotlib.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
#plt.imshow(img1) #this verified that the found coordinates are correct

#P = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(img_1_coor,img_2_coor)
H, s = cv2.findHomography (img_1_coor,img_2_coor)
print(s)
perspective = cv2.warpPerspective(img1, H, img2.shape[:2])
plt.imshow(perspective)
#the resulting image
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGoTT.png)
I want the output to be like image 1 with point-of-view(camera angle) as image 2. If this is not possible, vice versa would also be helpful to have image 2 with the point of view as image 1.

Can someone tell if it's possible to use coordinates of the object in image to change the perspective of full-image, if yes is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a computer vision package that implements the perspective transform (e.g. OpenCV or whatever they use nowadays). It is a fairly common computer vision operation. It is also known less properly as corner-pinning.

If you wish to implement it yourself as an exercise, you may look at [the Direct Linear Transform](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/5636/4714) where you solve your matrix problem in homogenous coordinates, possibly by using a singular value decomposition.